# Concerning "Lex talionis," is there a stronger word than "retaliation"?

Tags: expressions

"lex talionis": (Latin for "law of retaliation") sometimes referred to as the "eye for an eye " principle, a retaliatory action taken with a degree equal to the original offence.
Is there a word (in no particular language) that is similar to lex talionis but the retaliatory action that is taken is of a much higher degree (much more violent for example) than the original offence?

Comment: Are you just looking for *escalation*, or do you want a more specific term that only refers to retaliation in a legal context? A *feedback loop* is a related concept.

Comment: Perhaps the word you want is simply "law." A life for an eye, a life for a tooth, a life for a limb: such was justice in many societies, and often remains so in practical terms. Against such prospects, an eye for an eye is merciful.

Comment: Stabbing someone’s eye out or pulling their teeth out of their mouth isn’t violent or extreme enough for you? I suppose the result of ever-escalating _leges talionis_ would be a **vendetta**, which by definition is very violent; is that the kind of thing you’re looking for?

Comment: Two eyes for one eye?

Comment: The entire thrust of the [_eye for an eye_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_for_an_eye) article on Wikipedia is that civilisations (civilisation being a prerequisite for law) _restrict_ retaliatory violence to reciprocity. Hard to prove a negative but there probably isn't a term for this, as it may be antithetical to the very idea of law. That's not to say it didn't happen, though... there was collective responsibility with horribly disproportionate punishment in Legalist China, but no proper rule of law; prescribed disproportionate punishment probably means arbitrary rule in practice.

Comment: If you're looking for some *complimentary* expression for your concept, I think you're out of kilter with the current spirit of the age. Nobody has a good word for ***disproportionate response*** these days. Though I did find out yesterday that some people in the US are halfway to convincing themselves that when the founding fathers decided to outlaw "cruel and unusual punishment", what they really meant was that the death penalty is "unconstitutional".

Comment: Apparently it's *the Chicago way*: "He pulls a knife, you pull a gun. He sends one of yours to the hospital, you send one of his to the morgue! That's the Chicago way!" (*The Untouchables*, David Mamet)

Answer (score 2):

The US military uses the term **punitive measures**.

The introduction to [US Army and the Strategy of Punitive Measures](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/AD1022185) gives an illustration of when they used this:

> Prior to World War II, the U.S. Army had a number of conflicts in which
> it was successful in gaining and maintaining an advantage over its
> opponent. This success in many examples can be attributed to the use
> of **punitive measures**, which created the conditions for the
> capitulation of the enemy...
>
> Mark Grimsley's "The Hard Hand Of War Union Military Policy Toward
> Southern Civilians, 1861-1865" describes how at the onset
> of the conflict the strategy of the Union was to gain a quick and
> decisive victory while relying on conciliation to win the southern
> public's support. The author describes how conciliation failed, and
> measures that induced fear with a sense of Northern inevitable victory
> were critical to breaking the will of the Southern populace.
>
> Sheridan's and Sherman's use of controlled devastation
> against the general population of the Confederate states: The directed
> actions included burning or destroying property and crops that
> supported the Confederate war effort or the personal property of known
> secessionists.

Comment: aka **scorched-earth policy**.

Answer (score 0):

**reprisal**

> (in warfare) retaliation against an enemy, for injuries received, by the infliction of equal or greater injuries.

dictionary.com

Comment: "reprisal" is too broad a word/expression for what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something expressing a disproportionate (overly) response. For example you're  sitting at home watching TV, suddenly some thugs smash their way into the house and bash you and your wife and steal various items. You end up finding out who did this. You track them down and kill them all. This would be considered a disproportionate reaction. I was wondering if there is a term for such an overreaction? My friend just suggested "justice", but he has a different grasp of disproportionate than I do.

Comment: Vengeance would be another word for this, but, hey, I turn the other cheek.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:
disproportionate retribution
excessive retribution
surpassing retribution
intensified retribution
escalated retribution
two eyes for one/an eye

Many sources explain the phrase "eye for an eye" might better be read as "only one eye for one eye". Wikipedia's article begins with this variation.

> Under Babylonian and Hebrew Law, the “eye for an eye” law was intended
>   to restrict compensation to the value of the loss; thus, it might be
>   better read “only one eye for one eye”.  [Catholic Herald](http://www.catholicherald.co.uk/commentandblogs/2012/11/23/an-eye-for-an-eye-and-a-tooth-for-a-tooth-has-brought-israel-and-gaza-to-the-edge-of-destruction-it-seems-inevitable-but-its-just-not-practical-politics/)
>
> An accurate reading of the biblical phrase "an eye for an eye" in
>   Exodus and Leviticus is said to be: 'only one eye for one eye'
>   [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_for_an_eye)

I believe the meaning of "two eyes for an eye" is easily understandable. Interestingly, it's also part of the lyrics in a [Megadeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth) song:

> Vengeance breeding greater vengeance, two eyes for one eye
>  [Lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/death-from-within-lyrics-megadeth.html)

Further, the phrase "two eyes for an eye" is much more popular (about 50,000 hits on Google search, and gives results such as these:

> "Two Eyes for an Eye: The Neuroscience of Force Escalation"
>   [sciencemag.org](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/301/5630/187)
>
> Two eyes for an eye: 
> The role of retribution in Israel’s military
>   thinking
>   [Article from The Economist](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2009/01/08/two-eyes-for-an-eye)
>
> I don't believe in an eye for an eye, I believe in two eyes for an
>   eye. 
> [Quote from Bas Rutten, famous professional fighter, link to
>   video here](https://youtu.be/QszYRlWy3eo?t=4m52s)

Also note that as explained in the Wikipedia article given below and the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, "retribution", contrasted with revenge or vengeance, is less loaded with connotations of personal emotions and desire to get back at someone, and has more to do with justice generally.

The idea of an "eye for an eye", or lex talionis, falls under the theory of justice called retributive justice. A word that pops up often in this subject is "proportionality". Often we see proportionality:

> then thou shalt give life for life, Eye for eye, tooth for tooth, hand
>   for hand, foot for foot, Burning for burning, wound for wound, stripe
>   for stripe.
>  [Exodus 20: 23-25 KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2021-23&version=KJV)

Sometimes we don't. The following is from the exact same chapter:

> 16 “Anyone who kidnaps someone is to be put to death, whether the
>   victim has been sold or is still in the kidnapper’s possession.
>  17
>   “Anyone who curses their father or mother is to be put to death.
>   [Exodus 20: 16-17 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2021-23&version=KJV)

The reason I'm making a point about "proportionality" is that if you don't find your term and need to make one up, you'll most likely want to focus on this aspect.

> Proportionality requires that the level of punishment be related to
>   the severity of the offending behaviour. An accurate reading of the
>   biblical phrase "an eye for an eye" in Exodus and Leviticus is said to
>   be: 'only one eye for one eye' 
> [Retributive justice at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retributive_justice#Proportionality)
>
> (3) that it is morally impermissible intentionally to punish the
>   innocent or to inflict disproportionately large punishments on
>   wrongdoers.
>   [Retributive justice at Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justice-retributive/)

Personally I'd be surprised if there weren't a term, or at least a military doctrine or policy practised by a nation. I say this because in wartime you see this all the time, retaliatory strikes hardly ever are carried out on a measure for measure basis, they always tend to escalate.

Comment: _Two eyes for an eye_ would work **so** much better if only English had a dual number to draw on, similar to a language like Sanskrit where नेत्रे नेत्राय _netre netrāya_ works very elegantly (not sure if the dative is the proper case to use for this, but it’ll do for illustrative purposes).

Answer (score 0):

As a single word describing an "**unrelenting**" variety of "**Law of retaliation**", you could use the single word "**Lawlessness**". In fact, you could add the suffix **-ness** to several words below to add the "**excessiveness**" component to a retaliation. I also can't really imagine what a "**Law of excess-retaliation**" would be in Latin or any other language.

Although "**Lex Talionis**" does sound harsh, it is still based on "**legal or acceptable**" behavior concepts. They are described in your examples as actions of "**Justice**". In the case of "Lex Talionis", "**actions of equal nature**" results in a "**just**" expression of reciprocity or punishment rendered. It would seem that opposing concepts, like "**excessive retaliation**", could only be described using adjectives like "**Unjust**", "**Lawless**", "**Ruthless**", or "**Merciless**" as they would apply to any reciprocal action or punishment.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unjust

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lawlessness

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruthless

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/merciless

Answer (score 0):

I like:
***retribution***

> the act of punishing or taking vengeance for wrongdoing, sin, or injury ([Farlex Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/retribution))

Or if you want something more casual:
***payback***

> retribution or revenge ([Farlex Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/payback))